# Only allow social authentication django-rest-auth

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I would like to use django-rest-auth to build an API that supports on social authentication through facebook. I would also like to keep non-social auth available for admin links, but nothing beyond that.

Currently, my urls.py looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('api/v0/', include(router.urls)),
  path('api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token),
  path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', 
       namespace='rest_framework')),

  re_path(r'^logout/$', ra_views.LogoutView.as_view(), 
          name='rest_logout'),
  re_path(r'^rest-auth/facebook/$', FacebookLogin.as_view(), 
          name='fb_login'),

  # the 'api-root' from django rest-frameworks default router
  # http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api guide/routers/#defaultrouter
  re_path(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('api-root'), 
          permanent=False)),
]
```

Has anyone attempted this before? Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you have ***non-social authentication*** in your project?

Comment: Only for admin, normal users that use the API to create accounts can only authenticate via facebook.